# apache rewrite rule not working...trying to combine css and javascript

Tags: php, javascript, css, apache, .htaccess

using php5, apache2.2

I'm trying to combine my css and javascript files into one file as per this tutorial:
http://rakaz.nl/2006/12/make-your-pages-load-faster-by-combining-and-compressing-javascript-and-css-files.html

I don't think the .htaccess rewrite is working right.  Here's my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteRule ^css/(.*\.css) combine.php?type=css&files=$1
    RewriteRule ^javascript/(.*\.js) combine.php?type=javascript&files=$1
</IfModule>
```

I've tried exactly what was put in the tutorial for the .htaccess, but got a "forbidden" error, so the above is the only thing I got to work and at least not throw an error.

The webpage loads all the content, but just doesn't load the .css, or javascript.  I put some debugging inside the "combine.php" page to see if that page even gets called and I get nothing.  So I'm thinking that the rewriterule is wrong...but I don't know how to fix it.

Here's how I include it into the html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://somewhere.com/css/layout_2col.css,general.css" />
```

There are more than 100 posts of people saying it worked...i'm just not one of them.

Can anyone help?  Thanks.

Comment: Check the rewrite log (activate it with RewriteLog and RewriteLogLevel if necessary).

Comment: Just wondering, are you using Firefox and checking with Firebug? I find that helps me figure these problems out in a really efficient manner.

Comment: firebug says there are no files.

Comment: Tried to activate rewrite log like this in the .htaccess file but getting 500 internal server error:     <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
 RewriteLogLevel 9
 RewriteLog "/var/log/rewrite.log" 
 RewriteRule ^css/(.*\.css) combine.php?type=css&files=$1
 RewriteRule ^javascript/(.*\.js) combine.php?type=javascript&files=$1
</IfModule>

Comment: Are you testing this in your home directory?  There are sometimes issues with mod.rewrite there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem at this link: http://www.issociate.de/board/post/294029/RewriteEngine_causes_403_Forbidden_error.html

The freeBSD directory inside the httpd.conf needed to have: "Options +FollowSymLinks"...once i added this the forbidden error went away and all worked like it was suppossed to.

Thanks to everyone who helped me troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

@Ronedog: Try without `IfModule` --

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^css/(.*\.css) /combine.php?type=css&files=$1
RewriteRule ^javascript/(.*\.js) /combine.php?type=javascript&files=$1
```

Comment: Ok, I've removed the <if module> but now I'm getting a "Forbidden to access / " error message and nothing loads. Thanks for your help the .htaccess now is: RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^css/(.*\.css) combine.php?type=css&files=$1
RewriteRule ^javascript/(.*\.js) combine.php?type=javascript&files=$1

Comment: @Ronedog: Set `combine.php`'s access attributes to `755`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I changed combine.php to 755, but still getting "You don't have permission to access / on this server." error.

Comment: @Ronedog: Create a new folder, put `combine.php` in it and then try to access it directly in your browser. Otherwise, if your server is FreeBSD, by any chance, see -- http://www.lost-in-code.com/server-management/403-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server/

Comment: My server is freeBSD, thanks for the link. I have read the articles and made sure the directory indexes are set up.  If I "comment out" all the rewrite rules, then access "combine.php" directly it works great, there is no forbidden error.  But when I include the rewrite lines in the .htaccess file i get the forbidden error and can't access anything in the folder...it's almost acting like the rewrite rule doesn't work and blows out then blocks all access, but I don't get a syntax error.  there has to be something simple i'm just not seeing. :(

Comment: I found the problem.  freeBSD directory inside the httpd.conf needed to have: "Options +FollowSymLinks"...once i added this the forbidden error went away and all worked like it was suppossed to.

Answer (score 0):

The Tag `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` only works in the apache-configuration.

In your .htaccess file you have to start with

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
```

followed by your conditions.

The hole block:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^css/(.*\.css) combine.php?type=css&files=$1
RewriteRule ^javascript/(.*\.js) combine.php?type=javascript&files=$1
```

Comment: Ok, I've removed the <if module> but now I'm getting a "Forbidden to access / " error message and nothing loads. Thanks for your help the .htaccess now is: RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^css/(.*\.css) combine.php?type=css&files=$1
RewriteRule ^javascript/(.*\.js) combine.php?type=javascript&files=$1